# Grouped CollectionViewSource in windows 8 metro application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

Is it possible to specify CollectionViewSource element in the XAML code of my metro application as

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Name="groupedAppointments" IsSourceGrouped="True"
                      d:Source="{Binding Appointments,
                    Source={d:DesignInstance Type=dataModel:SampleDataSource,
                    IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}">
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="@DateOfVisit" />
      </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

But VS says

```
Error   3   The member "GroupDescriptions" is not recognized or is not accessible.
```

According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) CollectionViewSource should have this field. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the doc page for CollectionViewSource for winrt: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.collectionviewsource.aspx

The *GroupDescriptions* property is not available in WinRT

If I remember correctly this should work for you:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Name="groupedAppointments" IsSourceGrouped="True"
                      ItemsPath="ThePropertyThatIsGroupedByDateOfVisitGoesHere"
                      d:Source="{Binding Appointments,
                    Source={d:DesignInstance Type=dataModel:SampleDataSource,
                    IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}">   
</CollectionViewSource>
```